# finding a code in wordpress theme using F12 in google chrome

Tags: php, css, wordpress, google-chrome

This is my first question here I am new to all this :).
I installed a theme that shows 2 buttons at the header, for example: a Buy Now button. The theme does not have an option to delete the buttons. All I can do is change the button caption/text but I want to delete them completely. I have used the Chrome's Developer Tools markup viewer to find out which lines they are at, which revealed something like this

```html
<div class="header-button">
    <a class="button secondary is-outline" style="border-radius:99px;">
    <span>Sign Up</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

My question is how can use the same Chrome's Developer Tools to locate these codes lines and remove them.

Comment: They could be anywhere within your theme’s files, as the theme author has somewhat of a wide berth on how they organize the files for said theme. Use a utility like `grep` to recursively search for these nodes (or the code that generates them) instead.

Comment: It's additionally likely that it's generated "automatically." You'll want to search the code for "Sign Up" not that code piece specifically.

Answer (score -1):

Chrome Developer Tools can help you find elements on the page, and test/simulate hiding or removing those elements using **client-side** CSS or JS. For example in your code:

```
<div class="header-button">
    <a class="button secondary is-outline" style="border-radius:99px;">
    <span>Sign Up</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

If in the console you did something like (assuming 'header-button' div is first element in html w/ this class):

```
var buttons=document.getElementsByClassName(names);
button[0].parentNode.removeChild(button[0]);
```

That would remove the element from the markup in the loaded page. Of course - in order to make this a permanent part of the page, you would have to save this javascript to the appropriate page, using the WordPress editor.

If your intent was to remove these buttons outright, i.e. you never want to show them under any circumstances - then finding the page where this markup is saved and/or generated (i.e. using PHP) and removing this markup would be a better solution. i.e. there's little logic in having every user download buttons, then using javascript to remove them client-side when you can just change the markup to ensure these buttons are never served to the browser in the 1st place.

To do that, you'd have the find the page or template within Wordpress where this markup is saved and/or generated and removing the markup you don't need. Searching for classes (like 'header-button') in theme template or page should help finding the source.